# Setting a Fixed Size for CSS Menu Items

Tags: html, css

I am trying to assign a same size (Width) to all items inside in side a  CSS powered  Horizontal Menu Nav. as you cab see from the linked example the "li" size is rendering based on the length of the strings inside. Now my question is how I can set a fix size for items (For example: 80px for all)? 
Can you please take a look at following example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/hBDv9/

I also would like to know how I can center the Menu bar in box(div)

Thanks for your time and comments

Comment: I already did it. Did you read the post? http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/hBDv9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the width on the "a" elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/hBDv9/2/

You can also apply text centering on the "a", if you need that.

Comment: You don't need `display: inline-block`, just fyi.

Comment: True - didn't notice the "float" declaration.

Comment: Thanks Brilliand this works, Can you please let me know how I can center the text elements(Items) in boxes(li)?

Comment: `text-align: center` on the `a` will do that, if I'm understanding what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot you have a great understanding of what I meant :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add `width: 80px;` to `#nav li a` and `#nav li a:hover`.

Comment: Hi Elliot, Thanks but this just works on hover! Now I have perfect size of 80 px but just on hover!

Comment: Make sure you added it to `#nav li a` as well.

Comment: yes I did and it works on hover but not in normal situation !

Comment: Sorry I think I miss the a @ "#nav li a" from your comment, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

To get the li elements the same size you need to use:

```
#nav li {
  display:inline-block;
  width:80px;
}
```

To center one element inside of another:

```
div.wrapper { width:100%;}
div.wrapper .centered {
  display:inline-block;
  width:80%; // or whatever you want it to be
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Hi MaddHacker, thanks for centering part but the first part not working